# Как быстро построить дерево доменов леса?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Мне нужно построить дерево **[доменов леса](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759073(v=ws.10).aspx)**. Для этого я использую этот код:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

...

List<Domain> domains = new List<Domain>(); // flat list of domains
foreach (Domain dom in Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains)
{
    try
    {
        domains.Add(dom);
        var de = dom.GetDirectoryEntry();
        // Здесь у меня есть de.Guid и de.Parent.Guid по которым дерево можно построить
    }
    catch () {} // для простоты оставил пустым.
}
```

Код работает нормально, но когда один или несколько доменов становятся не доступными, ответ может идти долго (**[Domain.GetDirectoryEntry()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getdirectoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx)**), пока не выкенет исключение. Но с помощью Active Directory Domains and Trusts возможно заполучить все деревья леса довольно быстро, даже с доменами, которые в отключке, что наводит меня на мысль что где-то есть кэш доменов.

**Вопрос**:

Если этот кэш находится в **[Global Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/how-global-catalog-servers-work(v=ws.10).aspx)** -  возможна ли ситуация, когда **AD** структура не имеет **GC**?

И как я могу выполнить более быстрое перечисление доменов леса, и построить дерево на их основа?

Comment: GC в AD есть всегда, через него синхронизируются контроллеры, раздаются групповые политики и т.д. Другой вопрос, GC не обязан быть на всех контроллерах домена, такое возможно. А по поводу перечисления доменов леса, не уверен, но попробуйте копнуть схему AD, там много полезного найти можно, может и это нужное вам отыщется.